# How do you selectively flatten a sublist in a given list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that looks something like:

```
d={{{1}},{{2}},{{3},{4}},{{5}},{{1},{8}}}
```

Is there a generic way to use flatten so that you can selectively target elements within a specific sublist or is another function necessary?  The output I'm looking to get is:

```
finald={{{1}},{{2}},{{3,4}},{{5}},{{1,8}}}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
SubsetMap[Map[Transpose], d, {3, 5}]
```

> ```
>  {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3, 4}}, {{5}}, {{1, 8}}}
> ```

Also

```
SubsetMap[Map[List@*Flatten], d, {3, 5}]

SubsetMap[Map[List@*Apply[Join]], d, {3, 5}]

MapAt[Transpose, d, {{3}, {5}}]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
MapAt[{Flatten[#]} &, d, {{3}, {5}}]

(* if you don't know the position, but know the elements *)
MapAt[{Flatten[#]}&, d, 
  Join[
    Position[d, {{3}, {4}}],
    Position[d, {{1}, {8}}]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a generic way to perform this function without specifying the positions?  For example I'm working with lists that are variations of "d" so the parts I need to flatten aren't always at position 3 and 5.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It will flatten all {{3},{4}} elements and {{1},{8}} elements

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to flatten by pattern rather than position:

```
d = {{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}, {4}}, {{5}}, {{1}, {8}}};

toFlat = {{3}, {4}} | {{1}, {8}};

d /. x : toFlat :> Flatten[x]
```

> ```
> {{{1}}, {{2}}, {3, 4}, {{5}}, {1, 8}}
> ```

Also works with general patterns:

```
toFlat = {{3 | 1}, _};

d /. x : toFlat :> Flatten[x]
```

> ```
> {{{1}}, {{2}}, {3, 4}, {{5}}, {1, 8}}
> ```